# Related Rates: Suppose that a point is moving along the path xy=3 so that dy/dt=2. Find dx/dt when x=5

Tags: calculus, related-rates

I'm just having a tough time understanding how to do the problem entirely, so being as specific as possible would be extremely helpful. :)

Comment: How do $x$ and $y$ depend on $t$?

Comment: Include the units and mention both $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$xy = 3$

or, $\frac{dx}{dt}y + x\frac{dy}{dt} = 0$ (Derivative of a constant wrt $t$ is 0) .................................... (1)

Since $xy = 3$ and

$x = 5$ (Given) .................................... (2)

Therefore $y = \frac{3}{5}$ .................................... (3)

$\frac{dy}{dt} = 2$ (Given) .................................... (4)

Now use (2), (3), (4) in (1) to calculate $\frac{dx}{dt}$

Finally $\frac{dx}{dt} = -\frac{50}{3}$

Comment: Is it clear now?